# Does the combination of electromagnetics and scramjets offer a viable potential for horizontal-launch?

Tags: launch, ramjet, mass-driver

Most horizontal-launch systems envisioned in the past, that used electromagnetics as a launch-assist, were subsonic. In order to conserve fuel during launch and to keep engine-weight to a minimal a combination of electromagnetic-propulsion, i.e. [maglev or rail-guns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_propulsion) and [scramjet engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scramjet) may offer a viable alternative for manned systems to LEO. A lot of electrical-energy storage systems would be required to create the required velocity in the launch infrastructure such that the orbital vehicle scramjet engines could ignite. An example of a lower speed system is [here](http://www.popsci.com/technology/article/2010-11/nasa-engineers-propose-combining-rail-gun-and-scramjet-fire-spacecraft-orbit). If the launch velocity could be increased to between Mach-2 and Mach-4 a manned system, using only scramjet engines, could be constructed. Final orbit insertion would need some additional rocket engines. The launch-track would need to be at least 10 miles in length to keep acceleration under 3 g's, and offer launch-abort opportunities.

Comment: The problem lies not in the theoretical doability, but in the complexity of such a system, compared to just building a larger conventional rocket to reach the same speed.

Comment: Building larger rockets runs into two major problems: Specific-Impulse https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_impulse and Return-on-Investment https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_on_investment . Larger rockets aren't necessary a better investment.

Comment: While not a duplicate, [this answer](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/5539/12978) to the question [Why aren't all satellite-carrying rockets launched from airplanes?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/5531/12978) looks like it might be relevant.

Comment: I'm not sure what this site could add to an article that lays out the idea, and was proposed by NASA engineers. Someone must think it's viable.

Answer (score 2):

The potential of a horizontal launch within the earth's atmosphere is very much limited by the atmosphere itself. At a low height the maximum speed is limited by the high atmospheric pressure and at medium height there is not enough oxygen left for the scramjet. But to get into a low orbit, much more speed and height is necessary, about 8 km/s speed instead of some 1.3 km/s for Mach-4 and 200 km height instead of only about 25 km. The difference in kinetic energy is impressive, about 38 times more for 8 km/s instead of 1.3.