# Can an orbital rocket have an airplane first stage?

Tags: launch, engines

The first stage of SpaceX's Nov 18 Starship launch was the Super Heavy. According to the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_Super_Heavy), it packs 3,400 tones of fuel. In the [launch video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MncsDqi82-g), it shows the rocket reaches 27 km of altitude at 2600 km/hr at t+01:44. The engines start turning off at 02:40. Assuming a constant rate of propellant consumption, the first stage spends about two thirds of its 3,400 ton propellant to get out of 1960s' SR-71's [flight envelop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_SR-71_Blackbird). With similar analysis, it got out of A380's [flight envelop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_A380)   at 6 km altitude and 950 km/hr at t+00:50, after spending about 31% of it's propellant.

Turbofan engines have a specific impulse 6-20 times more than rocket engines. The exponential relation in the [rocket equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation) means an engine with higher specific impulse would greatly benefit in cost, weight and payload. In addition to having better specific impulse, airplanes  need much less thrust than rockets for the same payload because the engine doesn't have to directly lift all the weight. Jet engines are just as complex as rocket engines, if not less, but arguably more mature as a technology.

In this scenario, a space launch system that uses a specially designed airplane as the first stage and rocket engines for later stages may save a lot in fuel and weight while not adding much complexity. The first stage will be reusable by design. For private space companies like SpaceX, that have drastically cut costs for launch and operations, and designed all of the rocket system on their own, this approach looks worth considering. This is different from projects like [SABRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SABRE_(rocket_engine)). What I mean is a totally airplane design, horizontally thrusting jet engine and wings providing the lift, much like the [Pegasus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northrop_Grumman_Pegasus) project but with a specially designed first stage instead of a commercial plane.

What is the largest barrier to using launch system that has an airplane as the first stage and rockets for later stages?

Comment: F-22's supercruise envelop at 20 km, 1960 km/hr at t+01:30, after spending 56% (1,900 tons) of propellant.

Comment: there's a whole [air-launch tag](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-launch) on the site to research. This question is going to be a duplicate of one of those

Comment: The first stage airplane - could possibly be practical for small satellites. But to design an airplane that could lift 3-5 thousand tons, you would spend hundreds of billions of dollars practically for no use.

Comment: @RussellBorogove actually no. My proposal is different, as explained in the second last paragraph of this question, "This is different from ...".

Comment: @pakieng The accepted answer on that question mentions general points that aren't specific to the SABRE concept, as does my answer. A jet booster is feasible, as [Dani Eder's proposal](https://yarchive.net/space/launchers/jet_first_stage.html) makes clear; it's just that it's only worthwhile if you're going to go with a reusable booster, and there have been relatively few serious attempts at large reusable first stages.

Comment: "_much like the Pegasus project but with a specially designed first stage instead of a commercial plane._" [Stratolaunch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratolaunch_Systems) uses an airplane specifically designed to launch rockets. Does this meet your criteria?

Comment: @StevePemberton yes, I mean a system like that

Comment: See https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5531/why-arent-all-satellite-carrying-rockets-launched-from-airplanes

Comment: Thanks for the link @Woody. The accepted answer on that question doesn't address some of the points I have raised here. As shown by the calculations, a large fraction of the rocket propellant is consumed within the operating envelop of common aircraft (not even purpose designed). Most of this fuel load could be avoided if the first stage was an airplane. The accepted answer probably misses the point of using the airplane as an alternative just for the first stage, not the whole rocket.

Comment: @pakieng I do not know how you can so badly misread that answer to conclude it "probably misses the point of using the airplane as an alternative just for the first stage." The various answers to that question thoroughly cover what would be the answer to your question, which is "yes (and it's been done), but [the answers to that question]."

Comment: @ErinAnne In addition to saying "badly" or "misread", can you please describe how my explanation is wrong? The only negative point relevant to my proposed arrangement in the accepted answer is about kinetic energy. The accepted answer calculates the remaining kinetic energy for a kg after the first stage separation, but fails to account for all the extra energy that has to be spent to launch up the extra fuel up the end of the first stage. The arrangement I am trying to ask about, potentially saves all that energy because now you don't need to lift all that extra fuel up to the 2nd stage.

Comment: @pakieng ... I look forward to answers to your question. My question would be "why aren't air-breathing strap-on boosters used? " First stages need to throttle back to limit thrust for MaxQ because launching through the soup of lower atmosphere produces so much drag. Thus launch vehicles are at the mercy of gravity drag. This is the perfect opportunity to use air breathing engines to conserve oxidizer mass.

Comment: @pakieng that answer is the literal best case, pointing out how much energy per kilogram still has to be imparted by the remaining stages (the rocket), except leaving out the relatively small contribution of potential energy. The question it answers is explicitly about airplanes launching satellite-carrying rockets; the answerer did not forget about the rocket part.

Comment: @Woody Thrust-to-weight is likely the problem here. Aircraft engines are extremely efficient compared to rockets, but they just don't have the massive thrust per kg that a rocket does. (See also "Why don't rockets just use efficient ion drives?") In addition, you need to keep them dry, so recovery would be a huge problem. You can't just parachute a jet engine into the ocean and pick it up later, you'd have to tear down the entire engine to clean it out afterward.

Comment: Been there, done that? [X15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_X-15), [Virgin Orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virgin_Orbit)… notice the pattern: small  and/or suborbital payloads.